# What does the sentinel value NULL mean in Android Developer JSONObject reference page

Tags: android, json, null, sentinel

What does the sentinel value NULL mean in [Android Developer JSONObject reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), cited here for convenience:

`Warning: this class represents null in two incompatible ways: the standard Java null reference, and the sentinel value NULL. In particular, calling put(name, null) removes the named entry from the object but put(name, JSONObject.NULL) stores an entry whose value is JSONObject.NULL.`

---

### UPDATE

All that I can find online is [this](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/sentinel_value.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the Standard Java `null` values in Json Object causes them to be ignored and do-not appear in the output. This is baiscally done to compact the output. Where as the sentinel `JSONObject.NULL` will add null in the output string.

An example will make you clear

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
jObject.put("First Name", null);
jObject.put("Last Name", JSONObject.NULL);
//Print jObject
Log.d("JSON OBJECT", jObject.toString());
```

This will give the output like

```
{"Last Name":null}
```

Comment: So the word sentinel here is a figurative speaking, thank you :D

Comment: @congliu Yup exactly ;)